# How to ignore a collapsed code folding block while copying in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a Vue.js project, and I have a rather large array of data within one of my components that takes up a lot of space in my file. I often find myself wanting to copy various parts of the code from this component, but I don't want this array to be copied.

In VS Code, I have the ability to collapse this array, but when I try to copy the code, the collapsed array is still being copied. Is there any way to tell the editor to ignore the collapsed code block when copying?

Comment: XYZ problem. First of all, don't copy code around. Second, maybe you could put the data in a different file (mixin)?

Comment: I'm working with chatgpt and I'm copy-pasting code all the time, because it's convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you're pasting the code back into VS Code, I can suggest a workaround: copy it as normal, paste, then collapse the same thing, and then select and delete the collapsed thing. Collapsing it will make it easier to select for deletion (less scrolling around). Note that you'll need to include the beginning of the line at the end of the fold due to a known behaviour that selecting the line of the collapsed fold only selects that line and not the folded contents (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/72422).

If you're not pasting back into VS Code, then a different workaround would be to collapse the fold, then delete the folded content as described above, *then* copy, then undo the deletion, then paste into whatever external program you want to paste into.

Also, if you're repeatedly copying and pasting large of chunks of
the same code within one project, I'd suggest you look for ways to be more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).